# Does Rev 20:12-13 allude to a third resurrection?

Tags: revelation, eschatology, resurrection

> Then I saw a great white throne and the One seated on it. Earth and heaven fled from His presence, and no place was found for them. 12And I saw the dead, great and small, standing before the throne. And there were open books, and one of them was the Book of Life. And the dead were judged according to their deeds, as recorded in the books. 13**The sea gave up its dead**, and **Death and Hades gave up their dead**, and each one was judged according to his deeds. 14Then Death and Hades were thrown into the lake of fire. This is the second death—the lake of fire. 15And if anyone was found whose name was not written in the Book of Life, he was thrown into the lake of fire.

A basic timeline of Rev 20

- The rest of the dead did not come to life until the thousand years were completed v5
- When the thousand years are completed, Satan will be released from his prison, and will come out to deceive the nations which are at the four corners of the earth... to gather them together for the war v7
- THEN I saw a great white throne...

Once the Millennium has begun, over the next 1000 years, the people who are **not** in Christ (those who *were* are given immortality at Jesus' return) will live a normal life and will die a normal death - these are still physical/mortal. Obviously, there will be a very different system in place - no more hospitals or cancer or sickness as we are plagued with now under the rule of the devil - but people will still die - perhaps of accident, old age, or murder, etc...???

> he (the devil) would not deceive the nations any longer, **until the thousand years were completed** v3

So before the "great white throne" judgement, all the dead have to be brought before the throne.

Is this a *third* (and final) resurrection?

> each one was judged according to his deeds v13

There is no mention of a judgement *during* the millennium - it comes at the end - after Satan has been released to deceive one last time.

> When the thousand years are completed, Satan will be released from his prison v7

If the sea gave up its dead, and Death and Hades gave up their dead... is this a 3rd resurrection prior to the final judgement and the second death?

Comment: In fact, there is a judgement during the millennium - see Rev 20:4 where the noun κρίμα occurs as an activity during the 1000 years.

Comment: Judgement as an function *of* the saints ruling under Christ.

Comment: It is not clearly define here but there is still a judgement.

Answer (score 2):

Some believe that those that were given, but rejected, God's offer of salvation (the unpardonable sin) will be resurrected and destroyed at a third and final resurrection.

- **First resurrection**: those that were offered and accepted salvation have been judged and given immortality (small number).
- **Second resurrection**: those that were not candidates for salvation during their lives (the vast majority of mankind).
- **Third resurrection**: Those that were offered and rejected salvation have already been judged and condemned to death (small number).

> …
> The third resurrection will take place near the conclusion of God's revealed plan for mankind. This will be a resurrection to physical life of all those throughout past ages who, though fully aware of God's truth and purpose, have willfully chosen to reject His offer of eternal life.
>
> They will be brought back to be justly punished by death in the lake of fire along with those who are unrepentant at the end of the second resurrection period. "And anyone not found written in the Book of Life was cast into the lake of fire . . . which is the second death" (Revelation 20:15; Revelation 21:8; see also Hebrews 10:26-29; 2 Peter 3:10-12).
> …
> — [The Resurrections and Eternal Judgment | United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/bible-study-tools/booklets/fundamental-beliefs-of-the-united-church-of-god/the-resurrections-and-eternal-judgment)

See [Search Results "third resurrection"| United Church of God](https://www.ucg.org/bcse/search/third%20resurrection) for further descriptions and sermons.